# Phonegap iOS appstore missing purpose string in info.plist file

Tags: ios, cordova, plist, phonegap

I am building an app using Phonegap, and I have been stuck trying to submit it to the app store. I have searched and searched and tried different methods, but I have not been able to get past this.

Every time I submit the App, I am getting the following response:

> Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose string.

I have tried multiple tweaks to my config.xml file with no success.

Below is my latest trial

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.domain.app" version="0.1.3"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>App</name>
    <description>
        Test App
    </description>
    <author email="admin@.com" href="http://www.com">
        Dev Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
        <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
            <string>App requires access to photo library in order to enable users to update profile picture with a photo stored in their library. </string>
        </edit-config>
        <custom-config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>App requires access to photo library in order to enable users to update profile picture with a photo stored in their library.</string>
        </custom-config-file>
        <icon src="Appstore.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" width="99" />
        <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icons/winwodws/Square150x150Logo.png" width="159" />
        <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.jpg" width="768" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="windows">
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" width="150" />
        <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/storelogo.png" width="50" />
        <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="www/res/screens/windows/splashscreen.png" width="620" />
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" width="150" />
        <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" width="106" />
        <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.png" width="70" />
        <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.png" width="71" />
        <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" width="170" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" width="360" />
        <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.png" width="744" />
        <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screens/windows/splashscreen.png" width="1152" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.4.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="^1.2.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^3.0.0">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Camera used to upload a new profile picture" />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Library is used to choose and upload a new profile picture" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" spec="^1.2.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^5.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="^1.0.8" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-insomnia" spec="^4.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="^2.0.0">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Camera used to upload a new profile picture" />
        <variable name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Microphone is not used in this app" />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Library is used to choose and upload a new profile picture" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-contentsync" spec="^1.4.1" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility" spec="^1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <platform name="browser">
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" />
        <!-- defaults to "/img/logo.png" -->
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
        <!-- defaults to "3000" -->
        <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="white" />
        <!-- defaults to "#464646" -->
        <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
        <!-- defaults to "true" -->
        <preference name="SplashScreenWidth" value="600" />
        <!-- defaults to "170" -->
        <preference name="SplashScreenHeight" value="300" />
        <!-- defaults to "200" -->
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Daniel

Comment: Are you verifying that the plist file itself is updated after you run `cordova prepare`?

Comment: I was using build.phonegap, the resulting plist was not updating.

I ended up using cordova to do an iOS build, and edit the plist file in XCode. Not using build.phonegap for my iOS version of the app.